# Class doesn't output any results?

Tags: ruby

I wrote a class and am trying to print the results.

When I run this code I didn't get any error, but it is not printing anything. It appears as a blank.

```
class Employer

  attr_accessor :id, :first_name, :last_name, :date_joined, :type_of_employment, :vehicle, :location

  def initialize(id, first_name, last_name, date_joined, type_of_employment)
    @employee_id = id
    @employee_first_name = first_name
    @employee_last_name = last_name
    @employee_date_joined = date_joined
    @employee_type_of_employment = type_of_employment
    @vehicle = "Honda"
    @location = "Toronto"
  end

end

emp1obj = Employer.new(1, "John", "Smith", "January 1, 2012", "Fulltime")
puts emp1obj
emp1obj.vehicle = "Honda"
puts emp1obj.first_name
puts emp1obj.last_name
emp1obj.location= "Toronto"
```

Can someone help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 4):

How are you running this file? It print the following output here:

```
Honda
#<Employer:0x00000001779c68>
```

Note that these are unitialized:

```
puts emp1obj.first_name
puts emp1obj.last_name
```

You need to use :

```
@first_name = first_name
@last_name = last_name
```

instead of

```
@employee_first_name = first_name
@employee_last_name = last_name
```

in your constructor if you want to initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

The below doesn't output anything, as the corresponding instances variables(`@first_name`, `@last_name`) of those *getter* methods, `:first_name`, `:last_name` respectively, has not been assigned any values.

```
puts emp1obj.first_name
puts emp1obj.last_name
```

Do as below

```
@first_name = first_name
@last_name = last_name
```

As per your code, `@employee_*`, not needed.

Comment: when I create a {object emp1obj = Employer.new(1, "John", "Smith", "January 1, 2012", "Fulltime")} it has the first_name and last_name right. So how come it didn't assigned there?

Answer (score 0):

It's important when you are starting out to understand what `attr_accessor` does. This is what it is doing:

```
class Employer

def id
  @employee_id
end

def id=(str)
  @employee_id = str
end

def initialize(id)
    @employee_id = id
end

end
emp1obj = Employer.new(1)
puts emp1obj.id
```

If you want to use different instance variable names you need to use them as the methods not the variable you used for the setter/getter.

This would work for you:

```
class Employer

  attr_accessor :employee_id, :employee_first_name, :employee_last_name, :date_joined, :type_of_employment, :vehicle, :location

def initialize(id, first_name, last_name, date_joined, type_of_employment)
    @employee_id = id
    @employee_first_name = first_name
    @employee_last_name = last_name
    @employee_date_joined = date_joined
    @employee_type_of_employment = type_of_employment
end

end
emp1obj = Employer.new(1, "John", "Smith", "January 1, 2012", "Fulltime")
puts emp1obj.employee_id
puts emp1obj.employee_first_name
puts emp1obj.employee_last_name
```